# django endpoint not returning all fields specified in serializer

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

This is Source Def:

```
class SourceDefinition(models.Model):
    source = models.ForeignKey(Source, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    special_id = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    ad_group = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    creator = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    config = JSONField(default=dict, blank=True)

class SourceDefinitionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    source = SourceSerializer(read_only=True, many=False)
    source_id = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(source="source", queryset=Source.objects.all(),
                                                   write_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = SourceDefinition
        fields = ['id', 'source', 'source_id', 'special_id', 'ad_group', 'creator', 'config']
```

Engine:

```
class EngineDefinition(models.Model):
    engine = models.ForeignKey(Engine, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    source_def = models.ForeignKey(SourceDefinition, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    schedule_def = models.ForeignKey(ScheduleDefinition, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, null=True, blank=True)
    ad_group = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    creator = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    where_clause = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
    config = JSONField(default=dict, blank=True)

class EngineDefinitionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    engine = EngineSerializer(read_only=True, many=False)
    source_def = ScheduleDefinitionSerializer(read_only=True, many=False)
    schedule_def = SourceDefinitionSerializer(read_only=True, many=False)
    engine_id = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(source="engine", queryset=Engine.objects.all(),
                                                   write_only=True)
    source_def_id = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(source="source_def", queryset=SourceDefinition.objects.all(),
                                                       write_only=True)
    schedule_def_id = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(source="schedule_def", queryset=ScheduleDefinition.objects.all(),
                                                         write_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = EngineDefinition
        fields = ['id', 'engine', 'source_def', 'schedule_def', 'engine_id', 'source_def_id', 'schedule_def_id',
                  'ad_group', 'creator', 'where_clause', 'config']
```

Returned value from endpoint using `EngineDefinitionSerializer` :

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "engine": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "en"
    },
    "source_def": {
        "id": 1,
        "ad_group": "YYY",
        "creator": "EEE",
        "config": {}
    },
    "schedule_def": null,
    "ad_group": "YYY",
    "creator": "EEE",
    "where_clause": null,
    "config": {}
}
```

Why is `special_id` not being returned in the `EngineDefinitionSerializer` endpoint response?  I also attempted to specify all field names instead of using `__all__` and same result occurred.

...........

(need more words words worcs words words words wrods)

Comment: Wait why in `EngineDefinitionSerializer`, **source**_def is defined as **Schedule**DefinitionSerializer and **schedule**_def is defined as **Source**DefinitionSerializer? Shouldn't it be the inverse?

Comment: @YuriNudelman Thanks.. that was the issue!

Answer (score 1):

If you have a custom filed in you serializer, like source and source_id in your case, you must specify it explicitly in the fields list. Specify all fileds one by one, plus source and source_id too.

Example, in your case:

```
class SourceDefinitionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    source = SourceSerializer(read_only=True, many=False)
    source_id = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(source="source", queryset=Source.objects.all(), write_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = SourceDefinition
        fields = '[source, source_id, filed1, field2, .......]'
```

Regretfully there is no other way to use `__all__` somehow with custom fields right now as of July 2020, [this is](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/599e2b183db846a632b1efd148e6bc97d926ee5c/rest_framework/serializers.py#L1074) the source code that parses `fileds` clause of `Meta` class, you can check out how it works, not too compilcated code

Comment: I tried explicitly stating all fields and same result is occurring(see edit to main post).   `special_id` will appear if I access a view directly using `SourceDefinitionSerializer` but with the foreign view as above, it is not appearing.